# Jenkins Nuget Unable to load the service index for source

Tags: asp.net, .net, jenkins, .net-core, nuget

Firstly, I would like to portray the system that we use our company. We are using CentOS 7. I have installed Jenkins and tried my project to build. Although building started, occurred some problems. I am sharing error message.

```
    + dotnet build Ekol.FFE.HttpApi.Host.csproj
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.2.0+41abc5629 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FFE/src/Ekol.FFE.Application.Contracts/Ekol.FFE.Application.Contracts.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FFE/src/Ekol.FFE.HttpApi.Host/Ekol.FFE.HttpApi.Host.csproj]
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FFE/src/Ekol.FFE.Integration.Rest/Ekol.FFE.Integration.Rest.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FFE/src/Ekol.FFE.HttpApi.Host/Ekol.FFE.HttpApi.Host.csproj]
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: What happens when running `curl https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`?

Comment: @mu88 read and write the contents of the file. there is no problem in terms of connection or other side

Comment: Are you sure about your credentials, if any?